# details of stochastic Expectation Maximization (EM) algorithm

Tags: optimization, joint-distribution, expectation-maximization, latent-variable, stochastic-gradient-descent

I went into a paper, *[Online EM Algorithm for Latent Data Models](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0712.4273.pdf)* (Olivier Cappé & Eric Moulines, 2009). I got confused by the first equation the authors wrote, the Q function:
[image]

Here the authors denoted $X$ to be the latent variable, and $Y$ to be the observed variable. My question is:

Shouldn't $f(X_i; \theta)$ be $f(X_i, Y_i; \theta)$ instead?

Answer (score 0):

If you [read a few lines above](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0712.4273.pdf), this is a model where

> The observation $Y$ is then viewed as a deterministic function of $X$
> which takes its values in the set $\mathcal Y$

This means that the *joint* distribution of $(X,Y)$ appearing in the $Q(\cdot;\cdot)$ function is the distribution of $X$.